# Bash not comparing strings properly

Tags: bash, braces

This is my bash file

```
#!/bin/sh
ENV=DEV
echo "env: $ENV"
if [[ "$ENV" == DEV* ]]; then
    RUNTIME_CLASSPATH=$(cat ../build/dev.classpath)
    echo "cp: $RUNTIME_CLASSPATH"
fi
echo "done"
```

And here's the terminal output:

```
~proj/bin$ ./test.sh 
env: DEV
./test.sh: 7: [[: not found
done
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Is there some other way of doing string comparisons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write a bash script, then don't write a POSIX shell script: change your shebang line to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

On the other hand, if you want to write a portable shell script, use the `case` statement:

```
case "$ENV" in 
  DEV*)
    RUNTIME_CLASSPATH=$(cat ../build/dev.classpath)
    echo "cp: $RUNTIME_CLASSPATH"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
if [[ "$ENV" == DEV* ]]; then
```

to

```
if [ "$ENV" == "DEV" ]; then
```

.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.